# sql scalar-valued functions incredibly slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, stored-functions

SQL Server 2012 - I have a view (complicated) and one of the columns needs to have anything non-numeric stripped out.  The following works to a point;

```
STUFF(dbo.campaign_tracking_clicks.tt_cpn, 1, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', dbo.campaign_tracking_clicks.tt_cpn) - 1, '') AS emailerid
```

I get an error if anything but numbers are at the end of the value.

I have a scalar-valued function'

```
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[KeepNumCharacters]    Script Date: 10/11/2016 1:05:51 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER Function [dbo].[KeepNumCharacters](@Temp VarChar(100)) Returns VarChar(100)
 AS
 Begin    
 While PatIndex('%[^0-9]%', @Temp) > 0  
 Set @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex('%[^0-9+]%', @Temp), 1, '')    
  Return @TEmp
 End
```

I'm using;

```
dbo.KeepNumCharacters(dbo.campaign_tracking_clicks.tt_cpn) AS emailerid
```

But, it's taking a very long time to execute.  I've searched and searched but without finding an alternative.

Comment: It sounds like this data should be in it's own field.

Comment: I don't have that luxury.

Comment: How many rows do you have in your table?

Comment: Try looking at the estimated execution plan, and it may suggest a missing index that would help your query.

Comment: @dubstylee The index would help with the retrieval of rows, but his problem is the processing of each row in the `SELECT` part, by the `KeepNumCharacters`, which won't benefit from an index.

Comment: There about 100k rows in the main table.  There are about 30 joins.

Comment: you have two similar PatIndex. try to execute it once inside the loop by doing: set @n=PatIndex(...) outside the loop, then While @n>0, Set @temp ..., then @n=PatIndex() inside the loop, End

Comment: I've decided......  you cannot get the numeric value of "follower8223msg4593" using SQL.  That one appears to be obvious but should at least return "8223".  Even "follower8223m"  will get an error in most cases or return 0.  It's hard to believe that such a simple task cannot be performed.  I truly could use some help here.  Just FYI, I'm coding in Coldfusion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, scalar user-defined functions often make queries slow. Sometimes very slow.
See for example [T-SQL User-Defined Functions: the good, the bad, and the ugly](https://sqlserverfast.com/?s=user+defined+ugly).

In your case I don't see how to rewrite the scalar function into an inlined table-valued function.

One option is to add an extra column to your table that would hold the result of your scalar function calculations. You can write a trigger that would keep its content in sync with the main column as the main column changes.

It will slow down the updates and inserts, but it will speed up your `SELECT` queries.